# UWP Converting of an IF statement to foreach loop for NavigationViewItems

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the current IF statement that is, for lack of a better phrase. "Functional":

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ColourSelections.TextColour != null)
            {
                TransfersItem.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                HomeItem.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                OverviewItem.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                SpendingItem.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                BillsItem.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                PayDatesItem.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                PeopleItem.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                // NavigationView header
                NavView.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                // NavigationView Button Footer
                ChangeUser.Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
            }
            else
            {
                TransfersItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
                HomeItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
                OverviewItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
                SpendingItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
                BillsItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
                PayDatesItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
                PeopleItem.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
                NavView.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
                ChangeUser.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
            }
        }
```

Im essentially declaring multiple Colours for multiple NavigationViewItems within UWP.

Im trying to convert this into a "foreach" or "for" statement and step through each "NavigationViewItem" within my NavigationView "NavView"

I currently had the logic of doing it as following. Its wrong but i hope the logic comes across:

```
 foreach(NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem in NavView)
                {
                    Foreground = ColourSelections.TextColour;
                }
```

Ther error states that NavigationView does not have a GetEnumerator which i believe means it cannot "count" how many NavigationViewItems there are?

I get the general gist of foreach loops as being in the following format usually:

```
foreach(ARRAY as VALUE)
foreach(CLASSNAME varname in ARRAY)
```

Any ideas on the logic for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to check in **NavView.MenuItems**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush myColor = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
    if (ColourSelections.TextColour != null)
    {
        myColor = ColourSelections.TextColour;
    }
    foreach(var item in NavView.MenuItems)
    {
        if(item is NavigationViewItem)
        {
            item.Foreground = myColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: throws an exception error: `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItemSeparator' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem'.'`

Comment: I need to exclude ItemSeperators from this. Any way to exclude this in the foreach statement?

Comment: yes I have updated the answer with that fix and also showed you a way how to make your OnNavigatedTo even simpler

Comment: if it looks better, you can use `foreach(var item in NavView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>()) { item.Forground = myColor; }`

Comment: it does look better but I think this advanced syntax might confuse you if you are a beginner, but for experts this is definitely better syntax :)

Comment: Right, interestingly, Tomer's solution works. Theres a syntax issue somewhere in your answer Tousee. It seems to not like the navigationViewItem.Foreground

Comment: haha I made a typoc mistake, u just need to write "item" instead of "navigationViewItem" these kind of typos happen when you dont write in an Ide :p anyways I have fixed the typo in the answer :)